# Accurate Signal Generator

Tags: c++, qt, signal-processing

I want to create an accurate signal generator in Qt.

For example a square signal that 10us (microseconds) generates 255 and 10ms (milliseconds) generates 0. 
I'm using usleep() in my thread but it sleep about 1ms!! when searched about it, I found that it's for CPU context switch.

```
//fp:frequency of signal //t:time of generate high (amp) // n:generate n time

void Thread::rectGenerator(double fp, double t, double amp, double n)
{
    double result;
    double T=1000000/fp; //(us)
    for (double i=0,ii=0; i<n*T; i+=_Interval,ii+=_Interval)
    {
        if (ii>=T)
            ii=0;
        if (ii<=t)
            result=amp;
        else
            result=0;
        th.usleep(1);
        qDebug() << i << "\t" <<result;
    }
}
```

As a result : rectGenerator(200, 20, 255, 12) execute in 12 seconds but it should execute in 60(ms) !!!

> So what is the best way to generate accurate signal ?

Comment: This isn't very Qt-related (more a generic c/c++ question). Using qDebug() in the loop will distort your results.

Comment: Yes.You're right and i changed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Normally what you would do is allocate a buffer that represents a certain amount of real time, fill this buffer with your generated signal, then schedule it to be played or saved or streamed. (You don't specify what you're doing with the signal, but since you're doing it with threads, I'll assume it is approximately real-time).

Assume then that your target sampling rate is 48kHz (standard for professional audio). Then you would allocate a buffer of 48000 samples of floats to store 1 second of audio.  (Using double is almost certainly overkill; high quality audio is 16-bit or maybe 24-bit, and 32-bit if you're mastering top-flight systems, so float is more than enough precision; double is wasting bits).

Then you would fill this buffer with your signal using a looping function very similar to what you have pasted above. But you don't use sleep or anything like that; for now, you're only preparing the data which will be played later.

So once you have the audio buffer prepared, you need to schedule it to be played. This generally involves you sending the buffer to the system to be played back at a certain time. Depending on the API or device, you will get a callback to fill up the buffer, when a low water mark has been reached, etc.

If your signal never changes, you can just generate the one buffer and keep reusing it by rescheduling it to be played. Depending on the period of the signal, you may need to adjust the buffer size to maintain the correct frequency.

(Note that a pure square wave as you describe requires theoretically infinite bandwidth to reproduce, with its brick wall edges; you should probably apply a low pass filter to band-limit the signal, which depends on your output device.)

Comment: Yes. The signal is real time and I want to generate it for 2-60 minutes. But my signal isn't an audio signal and its precision is 5 microseconds. I think i can't get my answer !

Comment: Ok, you need to be more specific about your setup then, especially the hardware interfacing. If it's not audio, then what kind of output are you driving? With some more details, I will be able to update my answer to tailor it to your situation.

Comment: To address your other comments: the duration doesn't really matter. You only need to generate a short buffer with your periodic signal, and simply reschedule it continuously for output with your hardware driver.  There are several manufacturers of high-end audio products that make cards featuring 192kHz DACs which would be more than capable of this precision. Examples are http://www.digigram.com/products/product_infos.php?prod_key=14950&mode=specs and http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Audiophile192.html.

Comment: I want to generate a signal in Qt and then run it on the "mini6410 board" with winCE on it. I think the board isn't important and i should write right program on my laptop and then replace qDebug() in my code with suitable function.

Comment: So you want to send this signal from your laptop to your mini6410 board? Using what sort of interface? Or do you want the mini6410 to generate this signal?

Comment: after I write my program, i should setup this on the mini6410 and so the board generate the signal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33627/discussion-between-gavinb-and-mehd)

Answer (score 0):

For accuracy in the 10 uS range, your best bet my be to offload the signal generation to dedicated hardware (FPGA or microcontroller with a real-time or no OS).

Comment: That's still over 2X higher than a 44.1k or 48kHz audio sample rate, and most non-realtime computers need to buffer a bunch of audio samples to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a 100 Khz signal, by far the easiest solution is to use a device that's designed to create signals in that range. A good soundcard [will achieve this](http://www.clarisonus.com/Research%20Reports/RR001-SoundCardEval/RR001-PCsoundCards.html) and is quite easy to program. Just load your sample in and tell it to play. Its internal hardware will do all the timing.